# When to use drop ears + nipples, and when to not?

Tags: plumbing, water, copper-tubing

So I know enough to use brass when using nipples on water supply lines (especially if they consist of copper and copper fittings). However it isn't clear to me when it is best to use nipples and when it isn't.

I've seen sink installations using nipples and many with copper just poking out of the wall. Same with toilets and other fixtures. So what is the convention for when to install drop ears with nipples and when to just tee or elbow the copper out of the wall (and does the UPC have any bearing on this area)?

Is it purely aesthetic or are there practical reasons?

Comment: Most drop ears I have met are bronze, not brass.

Answer (score 1):

The drop ears are used when the plumbing should remain stationary, usually at the termination of the water line. A shower head may have a nipple (or stub out) tightened to it, usually with a cap when pressure tests are run. But the type of material used for a nipple ,as you mentioned, is dictated by the existing piping. Early plumbing lines used galvanized pipe. If you extended the pipe you should have used galvanized fittings to avoid reactions or corroding between any dissimilar metals. I think drop ears are required by code for all shower installations due to the showerhead being adjusted and grabbed. For a nipple that is installed for a sink to a shutoff valve , the pipe is usually supported close to the entry point.